# Adjusting spacings and alignments in tableau using BookTabs, NiceMatrix and Array packages

Tags: tables, packages

Consider the following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{array,booktabs,nicematrix}
\definecolor{yesgreen}{HTML}{AFFA6A}
\definecolor{nored}{HTML}{E04B14}
\def \cagewidthW {0.2pt}
\newcommand{\clrCell}[1]{\Block[fill=#1,draw=black,line-width=\cagewidthW]{1-1}{}}

\begin{document}
{
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
\setlength\extrarowheight{-0.8pt}
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{c@{\hskip 2em}c@{\hskip 1.8em}ccc} 
\toprule
                   &         & Case a)                       & Case b)                       & Case c)                   \\ 
\toprule
\Block{2-1}{$U-s$} & Present & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}       \\ 
                   & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}     & \clrCell{nored}       \\ 
\Block{2-1}{$U-Y$} & Present & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\  
                   & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
\Block{2-1}{$Y-s$} & Present & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
                   & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

There are however, two problems caused by manual tweakings:

**(i)** The `@{\hskip <length>}` preamble instructions, used to increase the distance 'between' the first and second, and second and third columns, causes (I believe) the first colored column to be a lot narrower the the other two.

**(ii)** The `\toprule` and `\bottomrule` booktabs commands limiting the table contents cause (I believe) the first and last colored row to be a lot taller the the middle ones.

How can I fix this (i.e., make so that every colored cell is of the same size) while still having good alignment (words vertically centered)? Noting that I need to use the booktabs package on other tables within the document.

Answer (score 1):

Your table code quite good match what you like to have. So any improvements are quite questionable. You can only a bit simplified code as wel by use of `nicematrix` package (by qhich I'm not very familiar) or by use use new, LaTeX-3 based `tabularray` package. For the later code can be:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
    \definecolor{yesgreen}{HTML}{AFFA6A}
    \definecolor{nored}{HTML}{E04B14}
\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
\begin{tblr}{
    colspec = {Q[l,wd=4em] Q[l,wd=5em]  *{3}{Q[c,wd=3.4em]}},
    column{3-5}={bg=yesgreen},
    row{1} = {bg=white},
    hline{1,2,Z} = 1pt,   hline{3-Y} = {3-Z}{solid},
    vline{3-Z}=solid,
    stretch=1.5
                }
    &           & Case a)   & Case b)           & Case c)           \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c} $U-s$  
    & Present   &           &                   & \SetCell{nored}   \\
    & Future    &           & \SetCell{nored}   & \SetCell{nored}   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}  $U-Y$
    & Present   &           &                   &                   \\
    & Future    &           &                   &                   \\
\SetCell[r=2]{c}  $Y-s$
    & Present   &           &                   &                   \\
    & Future    &           &                   &                   \\
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I made slight changes to your code, but the message is that `booktabs` does not play along. By using a (wider) `\hline` instead, the cells are the same height.[image: a]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\definecolor{yesgreen}{HTML}{AFFA6A}
\definecolor{nored}{HTML}{E04B14}

\usepackage{booktabs,nicematrix}

\usepackage{tikz}% added <<<<

\newlength{\cagewidthW}
\setlength{\cagewidthW}{0.2pt}

\newcommand{\clrCell}[1]{\Block[tikz={fill=#1, draw=black,  line width=\cagewidthW}]{1-1}{}}

\begin{document}
    
\textbf{\large MWE}
    
{
    \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.6}
    \setlength\extrarowheight{-0.8pt}
    \begin{table}[h!]
        \centering
        \begin{NiceTabular}{c>{\hspace*{2em}}c<{\hspace*{2em}}ccc} 
            \toprule
            &         & Case a)                       & Case b)                       & Case c)                   \\ 
            \toprule
            \Block{2-1}{$U-s$} & Present & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}       \\ 
            & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}     & \clrCell{nored}       \\ 
            \Block{2-1}{$U-Y$} & Present & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\  
            & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
            \Block{2-1}{$Y-s$} & Present & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
            & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ \bottomrule
        \end{NiceTabular}
    \end{table}
}


\textbf{\large Modified}    

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}m{#1}}

\begin{table}[h!]
    \centering              
    \begin{NiceTabular}{c>{\hspace*{1.5em}}C{7em}ccc}[rules/color=black,rules/width=0.7pt, cell-space-limits=3pt]           
    \hline
                            &           & Case a)             & Case b)             & Case c)                 \\
    \hline
        \Block{2-1}{$U-s$}  & Present   & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}       \\ 
        & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}     & \clrCell{nored}       \\ 
        \Block{2-1}{$U-Y$}  & Present   & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\  
        & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
        \Block{2-1}{$Y-s$}  & Present   & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{yesgreen}   & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
        & Future  & \clrCell{yesgreen}  & \clrCell{nored}     & \clrCell{yesgreen}    \\ 
    \hline
    \end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```